# Automator / Applescript for "New Outlook" - "selected objects" doesn't work anymore

Tags: outlook, applescript, automator, outlook-mac

Following instructions from @hakan-serce [here](http://blog.hakanserce.com/post/outlook_automation_mac/), I'm using since a while an applescript launched by automator to get a link to a specific message in MS Outlook for Mac and use it in other applications.
Here is the script :

```
on run {input, parameters}
    
    tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
        set selectedMessages to (get current messages) -- selected objects
        if selectedMessages is {} then
            display notification "Please select a message in Outlook before running the script!"
        else
            set messageId to id of item 1 of selectedMessages
            set uri to "outlook://" & messageId
            set the clipboard to uri
            display notification "URI " & uri & " copied to clipboard"
        end if
    end tell
    
    return input
end run
```

With the last MS Oulook version, "New Outlook" disabled. Everything still works fine.
But when I activate the new look, the following command always return an empty list :

```
set selectedMessages to selected objects
```

Any idea if there is any new command to achieve that in the "New" look of Ms Oulook?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just received an answer from Microsoft support and I understand that AppleScript is not supported but will probably be as there is a ask for it "under evaluation"
https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/924856-the-new-outlook-for-mac/suggestions/39253423-support-applescript

Comment: Somehow it already starts giving 404 :(